# Java code to create and write into text file

Tags: java, swing, file

I am new to Java. I would like to create a text file and write the contents in it when clicked on `JButton`.

I have `JTextArea` and button "save" when clicked on button, it should create a text file in a location given with the contents typed in text area.

Before doing it, I was testing the following code to check if it can create a file. But it's not doing so.

```
try {          
    String content = "This is the content to write into file";
    File file = new File("E:/file.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(content);
    bw.close();

    System.out.println("Done");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: add a button, set a listener and post the code you have above...

Comment: if your JText is JTextArea, then look at JTextArea.write, nothing else, different method you don't need ....

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine, therefore the problem must be in the way you use it. Do you have an E drive? Is file.txt existent there? I suppose it does not exist. But if it does, does the user executing your code have the necessary privileges to edit it? If it does not exist, does the user executing the code have the necessary privileges to create a file? Do you have enough space on your hard-disk?

You `catch` `IOException` and print the stack trace. You should see your error there.

By the way, your code will not compile, as you do not close the code block of the `catch`.